# Bootstrap Scrollspy stops working after an AJAX call added elements to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap scrollspy plugin (v2.0.0) which works without a problem when the page loads first.

The navigation bar as well as the content sections get updated via ajax calls (add or remove menu items). After this scrollspy doesn't highlight the newly added items anymore.

How do I tell scrollspy to refresh? Or maybe attach scrollspy manually to the following code?

```
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="0">
    <div id="listing">
      <div class="subnav">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#cat2">Home &amp; Garden</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cat5">Computers &amp; Networking</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>  
      <div>
        <section id="cat2">...</section>
        <section id="cat5">...</section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 15):

scrollspy('refresh') will simply do what the name says!

In my case I added the follwing code after the ajax call:

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
  $(this).scrollspy('refresh');
});
```

Comment: Note that $(this) represents the element being watched from scrolling, NOT the nav bar itself. So, if you are watching the body for scrolling, you could just as easily do $('body').scrollspy('refresh');